# How can I tell if the results of an MCMC data-model fit are reasonable?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, model

I'm using an MCMC Python package ([emcee](http://dfm.io/emcee/current/)) to fit observed data to a 4-dimensional ($A, B, C, D$) model. After a run with 100 walkers and 5000 steps (1000 burn-in period) I get a result that looks like the image below.

The 2-parameters density maps look horrible and the (16th, 84th) percentiles (dashed blue lines) around the median (red line) enclose an enormous region. Does this mean that the 5000 steps I'm using are not enough? Do I need more walkers? Could it be that this is the best results I can hope for?

[image]

Comment: In the few tests that I have run, emcee is a pretty inefficient sampler (despite being quite widespread for a number of reasons). 5000 steps are probably not enough for your problem. To check this, do several independent runs and compare them. Run a bunch of diagnostics on the chains. Do posterior predictive checks. See Chapters 6 and Part III of _Bayesian Data Analysis_ by Gelman et al.

Answer (score 2):

5000 steps is typically little for MCMC. Some applications need to go to 1M - I would say 100K is a better starting point.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and provide more evidence in support of your statement?